# How to perform calculations on pandas groupby dataframes

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe which for the sake of showing a minimal example, I simplified to this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pnl':[+10,+23,+15,-5,+20],'style':['obs','obs','obs','bf','bf']})
```

I would like to do the following:

- Group the dataframe by style
- Count the positive entries of pnl and divide by the total of entries of that same style.

For example, style 'bf' has 2 entries, one positive and one negative, so 1/2 (total) = 0.5.

This should yield the following result:

```
style  win_rate
bf     0.5
osb    1
dtype: float64
```

I thought of having a list of the groups, iterate over them and build a new df... But it seems to me like an antipattern. I am pretty sure there is an easier / more pythonic solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do groupby on `df['pnl'].gt(0)` series with `df['style']` and calculate `mean`

```
In [14]: df['pnl'].gt(0).groupby(df['style']).mean()
Out[14]: 
style
bf     0.5
obs    1.0
Name: pnl, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Woah that was fast! You should receive extra points for the speed of your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's like it took ... Zero time.  Ba-dum-tsh!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pd.crosstab`, which uses groupby in the background, to get percentage of both positive and non-positive:

```
pd.crosstab(df['style'], df['pnl'].gt(0), normalize='index')
```

Output:

```
pnl    False  True 
style              
bf       0.5    0.5
obs      0.0    1.0
```

Comment: Woah that was fast! You should receive extra points for the speed of your answer. Thank you very much!